# How do i get table data from SQLite Database in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, discord.js, node-sqlite3

I am working on a money system in a discord bot, i need to store data in a sqlite database, but i can't seem to read the data, only write.

Code:

```js
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3");
const moneyDB = new sqlite3.Database("./databases/money.db");

...

if(cmd == "money"){
    const person = msg.mentions.users.first()
    if(!person) return;
    var info = moneyDB.exec(`SELECT * FROM money WHERE userID = "${person.id}"`);
    console.log(info);
};
```

I also tried using these: `moneyDB.run` `moneyDB.get` `moneyDB.all` `moneyDB.each`

They all output:

```sh
Database { open: true, filename: './databases/money.db', mode: 65542 }
```

Why is this the output and not the actual database data?
Is there a more efficient way to do this?
I've already made a different command for adding and updating data on the database, but can't seem to read anything.

Answer (score 0):

these functions of the sqlite3 module return the database for chaining.

you need to pass a function as second argument into db.all

```js
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3");
const moneyDB = new sqlite3.Database("./databases/money.db");

...
if (cmd == "money") {
    const person = msg.mentions.users.first()
    if(!person) return;
    moneyDB.all(`SELECT * FROM money WHERE userID = "${person.id}"`, (err, info) =>{
            console.log(err, info)
    });
};
```